# Can´t allocate dedicated host AWS EC2 for Mac instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I´m trying to deploy a AWS EC2 Mac instance.
During the process of setting the instance up, I get asked to allocate a dedicated host for it.
When I try to do it, I keep getting the following message:

> Your request for accessing resources in this region is being validated, and you will not be able to launch additional resources in this region until the validation is complete. We will notify you by email once your request has been validated. While normally resolved within minutes, please allow up to 4 hours for this process to complete. If the issue still persists, please let us know by writing to aws-verification@amazon.com for further assistance.

It´s been more than a day since I started trying, so the problem isn´t the 4 hours mentioned in the message.

Anyone has any ideas how to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you contact them via that email address?

Comment: Yes, but no answer 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the AWS account in which you are trying to provision those resources brand new?

Messages like the one you are seeing are usually seen in case the account in question hasn't been fully activated or lacks billing information.

If my assumption is correct check the root account email inbox for confirmation/verification email requests from AWS. And make sure that your credit card information is up to date.

Comment: Yes buddy, I think that was it. Now I get another error message, but this one I think I can solve. And yes, the account is/was brand new. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: @PedroRabbi glad that it worked out. You could accept the answer for future reference as per SO guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done mate! Thank you!